# Python web scraper moving to the next page issue with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Here is the deal. There are 257 pages of data that I want to scrape. I wrote simple code, which uses Selenium. It opens up the website and scrapes the necessary text of the first page. All works well. It creates the dataframe I need and all is good. The code is below:

```
url = 'www.sampleurl.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_size(800, 500)

name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pflist-itemtitle')
address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pflist-address')
contact = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='tel:']")

name_list = []
for a in range(len(dealer_name)):
    name_list.append(name[a].text)

address_list = []
for b in range(len(address)):
    address_list.append(address[b].text)

contact_list = []
for c in range(len(contact)):
    contact_list.append(contact[c].text)

data_tuples = list(zip(name_list[0:], address_list[0:], contact_list[0:])) # Everything is paired together

# Creates temporary dataframe of each tuple in the field_listingtype
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Dealer Name', 'Address', 'Contact'])

df = df.append(temp_df)

print('Scraping done on this page')
print('moving to next page')
```

I wasn't able to find a good id for the *Next* button to use with Selenium to click on and move to the next page in order to repeat the process, and so on for the next 257 pages.

I was looking into [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) to pass in the page numbers in required place within the URL, but I'm stuck. How can I do it?

```
def new_page():

    for page in range(2, 257):

        next_page = f'https://www.samplepage.com/page/{THIS IS WHERE PAGE# WOULD BE INSERTED}/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
        driver.get(next_page)
        print(page)
```

Comment: How do you go to next page manually ?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close if I understood you correctly...

```
for page in range(2,257):
    next_page = f'https://www.samplepage.com/page/{page}/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067'
    print(next_page)
```

Output:

```
https://www.samplepage.com/page/2/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
https://www.samplepage.com/page/3/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
https://www.samplepage.com/page/4/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
https://www.samplepage.com/page/5/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
https://www.samplepage.com/page/6/?field_listingtype=104&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B0%5D=215&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B1%5D=203&amp;field527110067894682300000%5B2%5D=212&amp;field527110067
    .....
```

BTW, it is probably better to figure out the `next` button issue instead of doing a `get()` on 257 URL's, but the above would get you there should you choose that route.

Comment: The issue seems to be: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'. And thanks for your reply, however, how do i get the driver to actually proceed to the next page and next page, and not just print the pages out?

Comment: So you have an element with type of List?  You need to loop over that and click them individually.  You can't click it directly.  But that doesnt make sense that  `Next` button would be a list.

Comment: I know right. the button itself, has a class. I tried it every which way, find element by class name, by class, however it is coming up with that error. it has an href next to the class. Obviously it would be best if i could figure out how to just click on the next button and this way move on to the next page.

Comment: I think you should edit your question, or delete it and start over, and focus on the next button issue with relevant code and HTML.  The passing of 257 URL's is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have one of two options:

1. got to the next page using URLs and open a new window with drive.get(url)
2. Or using *driver.find_element()*, like for example this:

   ```
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, self.next_class_name))).click()
   ```

Or by any of the selectors: *[4. Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)*

By the way, if you get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'", try using *driver.find_element()* instead of *driver.find_elements()*.

I thought you had the same issue as I had, that when I opened the page and there was a pagination, then I always had a maximum of 10 pages (limit) even though there was 60 or 80 of them.